# .drop() and .filter() does not work when running a Python function (def)

Tags: python, pandas, function, drop

When I am trying to run a function (def) on a dataframe in Python, **df.drop()** and **df.filter()** does not work, it returns only the original dataframe.
Can you help me where the missing magic is? Thy in advance.
I have tried different variations of .drop() but none of them works.

**Example:**

```
def standard_f(dset):
 scaler = StandardScaler()for i in dset.columns:dset[i+"_std"]
 scaler.fit_transform(dset[i].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1))
 return dset

standard_f(df.drop(["customer_id"], axis=1))
```

Comment: your `standard_f` is returning `dset`, but you are not accepting that output when you call the function. Perhaps you meant to do `df = standard_f(df.drop(["customer_id"], axis=1)`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to do this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
data = np.random.randn(5, 4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df['customer_id'] = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5']

df.head()
def standard_f(dset):
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    for i in dset.columns:
        dset[i+"_std"] = scaler.fit_transform(dset[i].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1))
    return dset.drop(columns=dset.columns[:-len(dset.columns)//2], axis=1)

df_transformed = standard_f(df.drop(["customer_id"], axis=1))
print(df_transformed)
```

which returns for df

```
          A         B         C         D customer_id
0 -1.085631  0.997345  0.282978 -1.506295          C1
1 -0.578600  1.651437 -2.426679 -0.428913          C2
2  1.265936 -0.866740 -0.678886 -0.094709          C3
3  1.491390 -0.638902 -0.443982 -0.434351          C4
4  2.205930  2.186786  1.004054  0.386186          C5
```

and for the trandformed:

```
      A_std     B_std     C_std     D_std
0 -1.377340  0.271539  0.639613 -1.752797
1 -0.977238  0.807545 -1.716846 -0.021368
2  0.478304 -1.256018 -0.196875  0.515721
3  0.656212 -1.069312  0.007410 -0.030109
4  1.220062  1.246246  1.266697  1.288554
```